# effective UI styling for iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, ui-design

My question is a simple one. In android, we can separate xml stylesheet from layout so that it can be reuse everywhere and edited easily for UI design change.

Is it also possible in iOS xcode? if can how (prefer if not from controller)? need libraries? what are good libraries for that?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Subclassing UI components?

Comment: you can use category class for that purpose .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [UICategory](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories) class for UIView for that purpose. create different methods for set `borders`, `border colors` , pass `bazier-paths`, `corner` `radius` and so many . this is just few of them. category is of UIView so you can use on `buttons`,`lables`,`textview`,`textedits` etc;

**UIView+category.h**

```
@interface UIView (category)
-(void)makeToRoundEdgeWithBorder:(CGFloat )borderwidth bordecolor:(UIColor *)color;

@end
```

**UIView+category.m**

```
@implementation UIView (category)

-(void)makeToRoundEdgeWithBorder:(CGFloat )borderwidth bordecolor:(UIColor *)color
{
   NSLog(@"height %f width %f",CGRectGetHeight(self.frame),CGRectGetWidth(self.frame));
    self.layer.cornerRadius=CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)/2;
    self.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    self.layer.borderColor=[color CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth=borderwidth;
}

@end
```

**Use it**

```
[yourlable makeToRoundEdgeWithBorder:0.0f bordercolor:[UIColor clearColor] cornerRadius:8.0f];

[yourbutton makeToRoundEdgeWithBorder:0.0f bordercolor:[UIColor clearColor] cornerRadius:8.0f];

[yourTextview makeToRoundEdgeWithBorder:0.0f bordercolor:[UIColor clearColor] cornerRadius:8.0f];

[yourTextfield makeToRoundEdgeWithBorder:0.0f bordercolor:[UIColor clearColor] cornerRadius:8.0f];
```

Comment: This isn't Swift - As it's accepted answer, not sure what OP is asking for, maybe provide Swift extension examples too.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, especially for beginner programmers, a category is not a class. In fact, there is no such thing as `UICategory`. Categories are merely a way of adding new functionality to existing classes.

Answer (score 15):

You could create your own styles using enums. By placing enums inside the Styles enum you get a nice grouping:

```
enum Styles {
    enum Labels {
        case Standard
        case LargeText

        func style(label: UILabel) {
            switch self {
            case .Standard:
                label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
            case .LargeText:
                label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
            }
        }
    }

    enum Buttons {
        case RedButton

        func style(button: UIButton) {
            switch self {
            case .RedButton:
                button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Styles.Labels.Standard.style(yourLabel)
```

You can also then make extensions for the styles you have setup:

```
extension UILabel {
    func style(style: Styles.Labels) {
        style.style(self)
    }
}

extension UIButton {
    func style(style: Styles.Buttons) {
        style.style(self)
    }
}
```

And then use the extensions like this:

```
yourLabel.style(.Standard)
yourButton.style(.RedButton)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also look into [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/). It's a design proxy available for most UI elements where you only set the styling once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Classy](https://github.com/ClassyKit/Classy) to define a styles for your UI in a more CSS like fashion. It's used and maintained byt the people at [Wire](https://itunes.apple.com/app/wire/id930944768?mt=8)

Comment: Thanks! Clicked on that out of curiosity. First line in the Readme file says `NOTICE: Classy is no longer actively maintained see: Looking for contributors` Therefore maybe not really a good choice.

Comment: As I said it is actively maintained. I know for a fact :) https://github.com/ClassyKit/Classy/issues/108

Comment: As you can see the last pull request merged was 22nd of December 2015 by [mikeger](https://github.com/mikeger) which works at the company I mentioned. Neither the company not the framework are going to disappear soon. I have no interest in you using it but I can vouch for it's quality.

Comment: Okay, sounds legit. Maybe the next commit should be removing that line in the Readme then. I'll give it a try! :) Thanks!